# UIViews and CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, transformation

I'm a little confused. Let's say I have a `UIView` named `myView`, and we have the following block of code:

```
[myView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f)];
[myView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f)];
```

Now, if I looked at this code I would assume that this would leave the UIView's size unchanged. However, it actually makes it half of its original size! It seems that UIViews have some sort of "memory" about what their original size was. Is this correct? This also seems like a very weird choice that Apple made, and I was hoping someone could enlighten me about exactly what's going on and why it is the way it is.

Thanks!

Comment: setTransform *replaces* the current transform.  If you'd like to apply a transform to the current transform, use the function variant without "Make" in it's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UIView`'s `frame` property is its bounding rectangle in the coordinate space of *its `superview`*.

Its `bounds` property, on the other hand, is the bounding rectangle in the view's *own* coordinate space.

The halving of the view's size, therefore, would be seen in its `frame.size` (because its size is halved w.r.t. its superview) but not in its `bounds.size` (because the view itself still has the same size).

Comment: So if I had a view that was 100 pixels by 100 pixels, and I called `[myView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f)];` on it, its bounds property will still be (0,0,100,100)?

Comment: Yes. (Note: `bounds.origin` will almost always be `CGPointZero` except when a view is only displaying a portion of its content. `UIScrollView`'s `bounds.origin` is its `contentOffset` and its `bounds.size` is its `contentSize`.)

Comment: That seems really strange. Once the view is scaled up, even if it's 200 pixels by 200 pixels, it still sees itself as 100 pixels by 100 pixels? Is there a particular reason why Apple decided to make it that way? Seems pretty unintuitive.

Comment: Well the view's coordinate space (or "backing" for lack of a better word) is still 100pt by 100pt even if it's been scaled up by 2x for display in its superview.

Comment: So this is actually different from setting its bounds to (0,0,200,200). Is there a reason to use one over the other?

Comment: In the 99% case, you will be setting and getting the view's `frame`. Re: setting the `bounds` to (0, 0, 200, 200), that makes the view bigger whereas setting the `transform` to a 2x scale keeps the view the same size and literally scales the pixels and applies an antialiasing algorithm.